# Split an array by a repetitive value

Tags: ruby

I have a variable length array of arbitrary strings. The one consistency is the string "hello" is repeated and I want to partition the array in groups by the string "hello".

So given this:

```
[
 "hello\r\n",
 "I\r\n",
 "am\r\n",
 "Bob\r\n",
 "hello\r\n",
 "How\r\n",
 "are you?\r\n"
]
```

I want this:

```
[
 [
   "hello\r\n",
   "I\r\n",
   "am\r\n",
   "Bob\r\n"
 ],
 [
   "hello\r\n",
   "How\r\n",
   "are you?\r\n"
 ]
]
```

What I have tried:

```
partition = []
last = input.size
index = 0
input.each_with_object([]) do |line, acc|
   index += 1
  if line == "hello\r\n"
    acc << partition
    partition = []
    partition << line
  else
    partition << line  
  end
  if index == last
    acc << partition
  end
  acc
end.delete_if(&:blank?)
=> [["hello\r\n", "I\r\n", "am\r\n", "Bob\r\n"], ["hello\r\n", "How\r\n", "are you?\r\n"]]
```

The result is right, but is it possible to do what I want with ruby array iterators? My solution seems clunky.

Comment: What would be the desired return value if the string were `["Ahem\r\n", "hello\r\n", "I\r\n", "am\r\n", "Bob\r\n", "chellos\r\n", "How are you?\r\n"]`? When you give an example it is helpful to assign a variable to each input (e.g., `arr =  ["hello\r\n",...]`) That allows readers to refer to the variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable#slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before)

```
arr.slice_before { |i| i[/hello/] }.to_a      
 #=> [["hello\r\n", "I\r\n", "am\r\n", "Bob\r\n"],
 #    ["hello\r\n", "How\r\n", "are you?\r\n"]]
```

or more succinctly (as pointed out by @tokland):

```
arr.slice_before(/hello/).to_a
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that does not use [Enumerable#slice_before](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before), which was introduced in Ruby v.2.2. It works with v1.9+ (and would work with v1.87+ if   `each_with_object` were replaced with `reduce/inject`).

**Assumptions**

I have assumed:

- all strings preceding the first string beginning with "hello" are discarded
- to match "hello" the string must begin "hello" and cannot be a word merely containing hello (e.g., "hellonfire")

**Code**

```
def group_em(arr, target)
  arr.each_with_object([]) { |s,a| (s =~ /\A#{target}(?!\p{alpha})/) ?
    (a << [s]) : (a.last << s unless a.empty?) }
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = ["Ahem\r\n", "hello\r\n", "I\r\n", "hello again\r\n", "am\r\n",
       "Bob\r\n", "hellonfire\r\n", "How\r\n", "are you?\r\n"]

group_em(arr, 'hello')
  #=> [["hello\r\n", "I\r\n"],
  #    ["hello again\r\n", "am\r\n", "Bob\r\n", "hellonfire\r\n",
  #     "How\r\n", "are you?\r\n"]]
```

Note that `"Ahem\r\n"` is not included because it does not follow `"hello"` and `"hellonfire\r\n"` does not trigger a new slice because it does not match `"hello"``.

**Discussion**

In the example, the regular expression was computed to equal

```
/(?m-ix:\Ahello(?!\p{alpha}))/
```

It could instead be defined in free-spacing mode to make it self-documenting.

```
/
\A             # match the beginning of the string
#{target}      # match target word
(?!\p{alpha})  # do not match a letter (negative lookbehind)
/x             # free-spacing regex definition mode
```